# WCF Service Library Won't Accept System.Web Reference

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I have a WCF project service library that is receiving an encrypted username and password. I need to encrypt my response back to the requested user. I created a separate service library and add the encryption methods in it. Because I am using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EncryptUser(key, user), 
  Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))`, I need to add a reference to System.Web dll. However, adding the reference to System.Web causes an issue with the WCF Service. Every time I compile, it says that the reference to USER.dll is not found. If I remove the reference to system.web dll, the WCF Service is not complaining, but I am getting a message  "HttpUtility does not exist in the other project are you missing a reference?"
How do I get around this given it is specified in the requirement that I use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed after going to the WCF project's property and change the target Framework to .NET Framework 4.

Comment: It was set to .NET FrameWork 4 Client Profile.